# can you create your own JTA transaction?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, jta

I am loading a large set of data into a database from a webservice. I am using eclipslink for persistence and running the application on glassfish 3.0. I run into problems on my test data set in that there are a few foreign key constraint violations. I am fine with the violation, I do not want that data if it is not complete. My problem however comes in that the exception is thrown in the container. That then marks my transaction for a rollback, and I get no data at all then.

I would like to continue using JTA but am not sure if I can do what I want to achieve, and that is create my own JTA transaction so I can control when it commits,etc. I am not sure if that is a good idea though as I feel by doing so I may be destroying some of the benefits of using JTA.

So is it possible to get a JTA transaction?

Comment: are you being given an exception from your attempt to persist? Can you catch it before it bubbles into the container and rolls back the transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the database work in a method of a session bean. Annotate that method with:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

It will be given its own transaction. The outer transaction will be suspended while it does its stuff.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Advanced_Unit_of_Work_API_%28ELUG%29#Integrating_the_Unit_of_Work_with_an_External_Transaction_Servicestrong text**

Read How to Acquire a Unit of Work with an External Transaction Service. Apparently you can snatch the UserTransaction and/or start your own by querying the container JNDI for UserTransaction

Comment: Thank you, I like the @TransactionAttribute because it is so simple, but Unit of work looks like I can possibly get a little more creative.

Comment: @grantk sure but it assumes you are using an EJB @TransactionAttribute that is